# How could I check if "this" pointer of a class is still valid in a callback function?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, lambda, concurrency, callback

```
class myClass
{
public:
    void fun()
    {
         async_do( [this](int j)
                        {
                            i+=j;
                        } );
    }

private:
    int i=9;
}

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<myClass> obj = std::make_shared<myClass>();
    obj->fun();
    obj->reset();
    return 0;
}
```

The code above, when we call `fun()`, it will call `async_do()`, `async_do()`will return immediately. When the async operation is completed, the lambda function will be called. But, while this async operation is still running, the object could be destroyed. When the lambda is called, the object doesn't exist anymore. What should I do in this callback function in this situation?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should not have to check this, it should be valid by design. Your async_do should capture the shared_ptr by value to extend the lifetime of your object for as long as threads need access to it.

Comment: [`enable_shared_from_this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this)?

Comment: Do you mean `async_do` instead of `void async_do`? If you have a `shared_ptr` already anyway, you can just use [`enable_shared_from_this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) and hand the lambda a `shared_ptr` instance instead of `this` to keep the object alive until the lifetime of the (moved) lambda ends.

Comment: Of course `obj->reset();` doesn't make sense, since you didn't declare `reset`. Even with the above it would of course be a data race and UB if `reset` accessed `i`. For that you need proper synchronization with e.g. a mutex.

Comment: As for checking whether `this` is still valid: It is fundamentally impossible to check whether a pointer is valid in C++ (aside from testing whether it is a null pointer value). That's something the user has to keep track of externally and which is why types like `shared_ptr` exist to help with that where they are applicable.

Comment: Sorry. It's `async_do()` not `void async_do()`. @user17732522

Comment: @user17732522 `reset` is a `shared_ptr` member function. The only mistake is that you need to use member access, not pointer member access operator here.

Comment: Hi. What do you mean by _"to use member access"_? @Revolver_Ocelot

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Given the notation I assumed it was supposed to be a `myClass` member function. If `obj.reset();` was meant instead, then effectively it could simply be dropped without affecting the example. OP should clarify.

Comment: @Ryan It is not clear whether you really mean `obj->reset();` or `obj.reset();` instead. The latter calls `std::shared_ptr::reset`, while the former calls `myClass::reset` which doesn't exist. Please try to post examples that are actually complete and that you have verified compile to avoid this type of discussion and the risk of the question being closed for being unclear. See [mre].

Comment: "Doctor, it hurts when I do this!" "Then don't do that." Don't try to check whether `this` is valid. Design your code so it will be valid.

Comment: I see. It's not a problem of language or library, but the structure the logic. Thank you guys.

Comment: This is a place where [`weak_from_this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/weak_from_this) could be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`weak_from_this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/weak_from_this) is useful in this case.

Use case: when you need to create a callback but caller of the callback doesn't know the lifetime of `this` and the design allows `this` destructed before callback gets invoked.

The difference between `shared_from_this()` is that `weak_from_this()` won't keep the instance alive but only try to access it when needed. It is important to note that capturing `std::shared_ptr` might prolong the lifetime of a instance until callback is released. It might not fit all the use cases.

Eg:
Requires only invoking the most recent instance instead of holding all the instances and do not want to keep other instance.

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nGPbPd3zK)

```
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

using Callback = std::function<void(int)>;

class myClass : public std::enable_shared_from_this<myClass>
{
public:
    Callback createWeakCallback()
    {
        return [weak_ref = weak_from_this()](int j) {
                auto strong_ref = weak_ref.lock();
                if (nullptr == strong_ref){
                    fmt::print("This is dead.\n");
                    return;
                }
                // use `strong_ref` as `this`
                strong_ref->add(j);
            };
    }

    Callback createStrongCallback()
    {
        return [shared = shared_from_this()](int j) {
                shared->add(j);
            };
    }

    myClass(int val): i(val){}
    ~myClass(){
        fmt::print("dtor, i:{}\n", i);
    }

    void add(int j){ 
        i+=j;
        fmt::print("i: {}\n", i);
    }

private:
    int i=9;
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<myClass> obj = std::make_shared<myClass>(0);
    Callback cb = obj->createWeakCallback();
    cb(6);
    obj.reset();
    cb(5);

    { // Scope of strongCb
    Callback strongCb;
    {
        std::shared_ptr<myClass> obj = std::make_shared<myClass>(100);
        strongCb = obj->createStrongCallback();
        strongCb(10); // <-- still alive
        fmt::print("End of obj first std::shraed_ptr scope\n");
    }
        fmt::print("End of strongCb\n");
    }   // <-- obj get destructed here
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
i: 6
dtor, i:6
This is dead.
i: 110
End of obj first std::shraed_ptr scope
End of strongCb
dtor, i:110
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture a `std::shared_ptr` of the object instead of the raw pointer to ensure that the object is still alive when the lambda callback is invoked. The callback will hold a reference to the object, ensuring that the object isn't destroyed until the callback completes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

void async_do(std::function<void(int)> callback) {
    // async callback
}

class myClass : public std::enable_shared_from_this<myClass>
{
public:
    void fun()
    {
         auto self = shared_from_this();
         async_do([self](int j) {
                            self->i += j;
                        });
    }

private:
    int i = 9;
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<myClass> obj = std::make_shared<myClass>();
    obj->fun();
    obj.reset(); // This will not destroy the object if the callback hasn't finished yet

    return 0;
}
```

If you can't use smart pointers, I suggest that you implement a minimally working shared pointer. The approach should be similar.

You can also use a token-based system by assigning a unique ID to every instance of myClass. Then, use a static map to hold references to active instances of the class, and when invoking fun(), provide the ID to the async operation. Inside the callback, check if the ID still exists. If it does, the object is still alive, and you can proceed. The following is a minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <unordered_map>

void async_do(std::function<void(int)> callback) {
    // ...
}

class myClass {
public:
    myClass() {
        id = ++lastId;
        activeInstances[id] = this;
    }

    ~myClass() {
        activeInstances.erase(id);
    }

    void fun() {
        int localId = id;
        async_do([localId](int j) {
            if (activeInstances.count(localId)) {
                activeInstances.at(localId) += j;
            }
        });
    }

private:
    int i = 9;
    int id;
    static int lastId;
    static std::unordered_map<int, myClass*> activeInstances;
};

int myClass::lastId = 0;
std::unordered_map<int, myClass*> myClass::activeInstances;

int main() {
    {
        myClass obj;
        obj.fun();
        // obj will be destroyed at the end of this scope
    }

    // ...

    return 0;
}
```